# How to get information about an NFT contract using Alchemy web3 SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nft

I am using Alchechemys [getNFTs API](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getnfts) to get NFTs for a wallet. The API returns a contract address for a given NFT:

```
"contract": {
    "address": "0x0beed7099af7514ccedf642cfea435731176fb02"
 },
```

However I need more information about the contract, like owner, number of tokens, etc. I went through the API specification but I don't seem to find a corresponding endpoint.

**Q:** How to get information about an NFT contract via Alchemy web3 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The Alchemy NFT API mostly returns data about specific tokens (such as its current [owner](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getownersfortoken-beta) or [metadata](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getnftmetadata)).

For collections, they only support a [list of tokens](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getnftsforcollection-beta) in the collection. Which you can at least use to calculate the number of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes looking, Alchemy updated the method to  [getNFTsForOwner](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnftsforowner-v3). This returns a list of NFTs, with pagination, that contains metadata, contract information, and opensea data.